# How to collapse a data bound control in UWP when there is no data in the field

Tags: listview, hide, uwp, bind, no-data

I am working on a UWP app that has data bound in a ListView. I have been trying to find a way to collapse (hide) a control when there is no data. For example, i made a simple version of what i am doing:

```
<ListView Name="lvwMaster" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CollectionOfPeople}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Person">
            <StackPanel Name="pnlOnePerson" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Name="lblFirstName" Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Name="lblMiddleName" Text="{x:Bind MiddleName}" Height="Auto" />
                <TextBlock Name="lblLastName" Text="{x:Bind LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Name="lblBirthDate" Text="{x:Bind BirthDate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Since not everyone has a middle name, i want the middle name field to be hidden when it is empty.

[image: example of what it looks like when run]

Any suggestions on how i might be able to hide the middle name field when the person doesn't have a middle name?

Comment: You should use a [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Value Converter

```
class TextToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string name = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

define the Converter as a static resource inside the page.

```
<Page.Resources> 
  <local:TextToVisibilityConverter x:Name="ConverterNameHere"/> 
</Page.Resources>
```

in your data template use it like this,

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Person">
                    <StackPanel Name="pnlOnePerson" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Name="lblFirstName" Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Name="lblMiddleName" Text="{x:Bind MiddleName}" Height="Auto" Visibility ="{Binding path=Text, ElementName="lblMiddleName" Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}}" />
                        <TextBlock Name="lblLastName" Text="{x:Bind LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Name="lblBirthDate" Text="{x:Bind BirthDate}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: you have forget to add converter in page resources:
    `<Page.Resources>`
    `<local:TextToVisibilityConverter x:Name="ConverterNameHere"/>`
    `</Page.Resources>`

Comment: Thank you Nuwannnz. Your solution worked. I did have to change the format of binding in the middle name in order to make it work.    `<TextBlock Name="lblMiddleName" Text="{x:Bind MiddleName}" Height="Auto" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lblMiddleName, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}}" />`

Comment: Please mark this as answer if you find this useful :)